# how my array contains empty item after merging?

Tags: javascript

```
// merge B to A
let A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let B = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

console.log("Initial A => ", A);
console.log("Initial B => ", B);
for (let i = 0; i < B.length; i++){
    A[A.length + i] = B[i];
}
console.log("Final A => ", A);
console.log("Final B => ", B);
```

I am trying to merge array A with B but in the output of Merged array its show some empty item after every new added element i am unable to find out the main reason causing it to happen, can anyone clear this scenario

Comment: how about using concat function?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: A.length increased every time you add something to A…

Comment: This [article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-merge-arrays/#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20either%20the,merge%202%20or%20more%20arrays.) 
 explains pretty well 3 ways to do it. Although IsoW answer is right too

Answer (score 5):

adding i to `A[A.length + i]` is making this problem.

just remove i and everything will be fine

```js
let A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let B = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

console.log("Initial A => ", A);
console.log("Initial B => ", B);
for (let i = 0; i < B.length; i++){
    A[A.length] = B[i];
}
console.log("Final A => ", A);
console.log("Final B => ", B);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the Array.concat() method:

```js
let A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let B = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
console.log("Initial A => ", A);
console.log("Initial B => ", B);

A = A.concat(B);
console.log("Final A => ", A);
console.log("Final B => ", B);
```

Comment: I am trying to learn data structures in javascript so i didn't used the default method but thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that performing `A[A.length + i] = B[i]` will alter the `length` of `A`.

1. Initially, `A.length` is `5`.
2. After you append `B[0]`, `A.length` is `6`
3. When adding `B[1]`, you put it in position `A[6 + 1]` = `A[7]`. You expected it to go in position `6`, because you expected to use the original `length` of `5` (plus `i` of `1`), but `length` is not `5` anymore!

To solve this, simply don't add `i` to your index of `A`. Putting something in `A[A.length] = ...` will always add it to the end of array `A`.

Alternatively, you can use [`A.push(B[i])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to append each `B[i]` to the end of `A`, or you can avoid this code altogether by simply doing [`A = A.concat(B)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to append all of the elements of `B` to the end of `A`.